# Concatenating multiple menu selections into string with all possible variations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936492/concatenating-select-menus-into-a-single-form-input/) an answer to a question about concatenating menu selection to string using javascript. 
I wonder if is it possible to change the **select elements** to **multiple** to create all possible combinations from selected values?

```
<form>
<input form="form" type="hidden" name="product_data[product]" id="product_description_product" value="{$product_data.product}" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#product_description_product_1, #product_description_product_2, #product_description_product_3").change(function(){
    concatenated_string = $("#product_description_product_1").val() + 
$("#product_description_product_2").val() + 
$("#product_description_product_3").val();
    $("#product_description_product").val(concatenated_string);
})
</script>

<select size="5" multiple="multiple" id="product_description_product_1">
    <optgroup label="Box size">
        <option value="Extra small">Extra small</option>
        <option value="Small">Small</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Large">Large</option>
        <option value="Extra Large">Extra Large</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select size="5" multiple="multiple" id="product_description_product_2">
    <optgroup label="Speciality">
        <option value="organic">organic</option>
        <option value="seasonal">seasonal</option>
        <option value="locally grown">locally grown</option>
        <option value="exotic">exotic</option>
        <option value="gourmet">gourmet</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<select size="5" multiple="multiple" id="product_description_product_3">
    <optgroup label="Type of box">
        <option value="veg box">veg box</option>
        <option value="fruit box">fruit box</option>
        <option value="fruit &amp; veg box">fruit &amp; veg box</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```

If I select for example:

- from first select element: Small, Medium
- from second select element: organic, gourmet
- from third select element: fruit box

return me different strings with all possible combinations

- Small organic fruit box
- Medium organic fruit box
- Small gourmet fruit box
- Medium gourmet fruit box

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use array to save the values?
A simple way would create 3 arrays:

```
var itemsBoxSize;
var itemsSpeciality;
var itemsTypeBox;
```

So, when user select an item, adds it to the array. For example:
`itemsBoxSize.push("Small");`

Finally, you access all arrays:

```
for (i = 0; i <= itemsBoxSize.length; i++) {
  var resultString = itemsBoxSize[i] + " " + itemsSpeciality[i] + itemsTypeBox[i];
}
```

Something like that!

Comment: I am beginner to programming. Can you please show me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's correct, but it's on the right way:
Note: it is still a little bit manual, but you can try to automate it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="result"></div>

<form id="optionsForm">
  <select size="5" multiple="multiple" id="boxSize">
      <optgroup label="Box size">
          <option value="Extra small">Extra small</option>
          <option value="Small">Small</option>
          <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="Large">Large</option>
          <option value="Extra Large">Extra Large</option>
      </optgroup>
  </select>
  <select size="5" multiple="multiple" id="speciality">
      <optgroup label="Speciality">
          <option value="organic">organic</option>
          <option value="seasonal">seasonal</option>
          <option value="locally grown">locally grown</option>
          <option value="exotic">exotic</option>
          <option value="gourmet">gourmet</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <select size="5" multiple="multiple" id="typeBox">
      <optgroup label="Type of box">
          <option value="veg box">veg box</option>
          <option value="fruit box">fruit box</option>
          <option value="fruit &amp; veg box">fruit &amp; veg box</option>
      </optgroup>
  </select>
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // It also is used to clear the array
  function initItems() {
    items["boxSize"] = [];
    items["speciality"] = [];
    items["typeBox"] = [];
  }

  var items = [];
  initItems();

  // When user selects items
  $("#optionsForm").change(function() {
    initItems(); // Clear items
    $("select :selected").each(function(i, selected) {
      var selectId = $(this).closest("select").attr("id");
      items[selectId].push($(selected).text());
    });

    showResult();
  });

  function showResult() {
    var s = "";
    var highestLenght = getHighestLenght();
    var partialLength;

    for (i = 0; i < highestLenght; i++) {

      // BOX SIZE
      partialLength = items["boxSize"].length;
        if (partialLength >= highestLenght) {
        s += items["boxSize"][i] + " ";
      } else {
        s += items["boxSize"][partialLength - 1] + " ";
      }

      // SPECIALITY
      partialLength = items["speciality"].length;
        if (partialLength >= highestLenght) {
        s += items["speciality"][i] + " ";
      } else {
        s += items["speciality"][partialLength - 1] + " ";
      }

      // TYPE BOX
      partialLength = items["typeBox"].length;
        if (partialLength >= highestLenght) {
        s += items["typeBox"][i] + " ";
      } else {
        s += items["typeBox"][partialLength - 1] + " ";
      }

      s += "<br>";
    }

    $('#result').html(s);
  }

  // What is the highest amount of elements?
  function getHighestLenght() {
    var highestValues = [];
    highestValues.push(items["boxSize"].length);
    highestValues.push(items["speciality"].length);
    highestValues.push(items["typeBox"].length);
    var highest = Math.max.apply(null, highestValues);
    return highest;
  }

})
```

Comment: I tested your code and partially is working. It creates combinations only for first select. But if i choose multiple values in second and third select it only updates the string with last selected value.

Comment: After reading many post here at stackoverflow and try many suggestion I believe I have found a working solution for my question and I want to share it. Please, keep in mind that I am a begginer so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/panosdotk/jemjmcvr/